# Square of a differential

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Just wondering, is this valid:

$$
\left(\frac{df}{dx}\right)^2=\frac{d^{2}f}{dx^{2}}
$$

Comment: Let $f$ be any non-constant polynomial. What happens?

Comment: Nope. Most examples will show you that this does not hold; for instance it will not hold for linear functions. Note that even in terms of differential notation, while the "denominator" in the second derivative is indeed $(dx)^2$, the numerator is $d^2f$, not $(df)^2$.

Comment: I see the right hand side as the second derivative with respect to $x$, which is not the same as the first derivative squared...

Comment: So if I have the LHS in an ODE, how would I solve?

Comment: @MichaelRoberts Not enough context to say. Plenty of such *nonlinear* ODEs have no elementary solutions, and may not even have a simple solution in terms of some non-elementary integral.

Comment: Could you take a look at my question prior to this? I'm really stuck on finding the method for the solution.

Comment: @MichaelRoberts It's easy to solve if you let $g=\frac{df}{dx}$. Then the equation is $g^2=\frac{dg}{dx}$ which has solution $g(x)=\frac{-1}{x+c}$. Integrate that to get the solution $f(x)=-\log(|x+c_1|)+c_2$.

Comment: @MiloBrandt I don't think that's right; you had $r''=-\frac{GM}{r^2}$, then $r'^2=\frac{2GM}{r}+C_1$; $\frac{2GM}{r}+C_1$ is not $r''$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Take the example $f(x)=x^2$

$$
\left( \dfrac{d\left(x^2\right)}{dx}\right) ^2=(2x)^2
$$

but
$$
\left( \dfrac{d^2\left(x^2\right)}{dx^2}\right)=2
$$

Which is a counterexample to your statement

Answer (score 24):

No.

$$\left(\frac{\text{d}f}{\text{d}x}\right)^2 = \frac{\text{d}f}{\text{d}x}\cdot \frac{\text{d}f}{\text{d}x}$$

Whilst

$$\frac{\text{d}^2f}{\text{d}x^2} = \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\frac{\text{d}f}{\text{d}x}\right)$$

Answer (score 3):

Beside the trivial solution $f=c_1$, as Paul Evans commented, the only solution of the differential equation $$\left(\frac{df}{dx}\right)^2=\frac{d^{2}f}{dx^{2}}$$ is $$f=c_2-\log \left(c_1+x\right)$$ This is obtained setting first $p=\frac{df}{dx}$ which reduces the equation to $p^2=\frac{dp}{dx}$  which is separable and easy to solve. Once $p$ is obtained, one more integration.

Comment: missing the trivial f = c

Comment: @PaulEvans. For sure ! I shall edit my answer and quote you !! Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

There are two *specific* formulae where this works, but that is all:

$$f(x) = c-\ln(x+a)$$

$$f'(x) = -\frac{1}{x+a}$$

$$f''(x) = \frac{1}{(x+a)^2}$$

and

$$f(x) = c$$

$$f'(x) = f''(x) = 0$$

Comment: There are an infinite number of options that work: -ln(x) + c

Comment: f(x) = c also works

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the exponent $2$ is placed differently for $f$ and $x$ should set you thinking.

$$\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}\text{ is neither }\frac{d^2f}{d^2x}\text{ nor }\frac{df^2}{dx^2}\text{, but}\frac d{dx}\left(\frac{df}{dx}\right).$$

The meaning of the notation is indeed a second order differential, i.e. a difference of difference, not a squared difference.

Then about any function will show you that the square of the first derivative isn't the second derivative.

---

Looking for counterexamples, we have

$$f'^2(x)=f''(x),$$ or with $f'(x)=g(x)$,
$$g^2(x)=g'(x)\implies\frac{g'(x)}{g^2(x)}=-\left(\frac1{g(x)}\right)'=1\implies\frac1{g(x)}=C-x\implies g(x)=\frac1{C-x},$$
so that
$$f(x)=C'-\ln|C-x|.$$